# How to split array object into 2 object with if

Tags: javascript

I have object like this:

```
data = [{"id":"3d59db2c-b561-4978-89bf-9aea17f14e2d","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"TRANSFER_DOMESTIC","quota":10,"tncDescription":"Free 10x transfer to any bank","points":7000,"validity":"2022-01-08","status":true},
{"id":"57db1973-7e42-4992-a4f5-ce578fb78b8a","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"TRANSFER_DOMESTIC","quota":3,"tncDescription":"Free 3x transfer to any bank voucher","points":1500,"validity":"2021-10-08","status":true},
{"id":"eacb400d-827d-4ab4-b515-423dbb90d927","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"TRANSFER_DOMESTIC","quota":5,"tncDescription":"Free 5x transfer to any bank voucher","points":2000,"validity":"2021-10-08","status":true},
{"id":"7b4cde23-ffb1-4f94-8d74-d1be4b379342","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"TOP_UP","quota":10,"tncDescription":"Free 10x top up e-wallet (OVO, GOPAY, Shopee Pay)","points":750,"validity":"2021-10-08","status":true},{"id":"92753ea2-0dc4-4605-a130-0c43f8f3b00f","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"PAYMENT_BILL_PLN","quota":3,"tncDescription":"Free 3x PLN bill payment fee","points":1000,"validity":"2022-01-08","status":true},
{"id":"9dc7de52-1174-43a9-abc1-c9889e2982ba","category":"VOUCHER","usage":"PAYMENT_BILL_PDAM","quota":3,"tncDescription":"Free 3x PDAM bill payment fee","points":1000,"validity":"2022-01-08","status":true},
{"id":"dbe15d75-5550-49cb-8b5f-42aa85c2246f","category":"VOUCHER","usage":"PAYMENT_BILL_INTERNET","quota":3,"tncDescription":"Free 3x Indihome or FirstMedia or Biznet bill payment fee","points":1000,"validity":"2022-01-08","status":true}]
```

I have category Jalin Offer and Voucher

I want to split the object into 2 object with 2 category. 1 object with `JALIN_OFFER` category and 1 object with `VOUCHER` category

Things I have tried :

```
let voucher, offer = []    
data.forEach(element => {
            (element.category === "VOUCHER") ? 
            voucher.push(element)  : offer.push(element)
        });
```

This code make error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

```
let voucher, offer = []
data.map((data,index)=> {
                (data.category === "VOUCHER") ? 
                voucher.push({
                    number:index+1,
                    ...data,
                }) : offer.push({
                    number:index+1,
                    ...data,
                })
            })
```

This code make error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` too

Any solution?
Thank you before

Comment: you did not assign a value to  `voucher` for starters. try `let voucher = [], offer = []`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `voucher` is not initialized properly. Try initializing it separately and try again.

```
let voucher = [];
let offer = [];
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by destructuring:

```js
data = [{"id":"3d59db2c-b561-4978-89bf-9aea17f14e2d","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"TRANSFER_DOMESTIC","quota":10,"tncDescription":"Free 10x transfer to any bank","points":7000,"validity":"2022-01-08","status":true},
{"id":"57db1973-7e42-4992-a4f5-ce578fb78b8a","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"TRANSFER_DOMESTIC","quota":3,"tncDescription":"Free 3x transfer to any bank voucher","points":1500,"validity":"2021-10-08","status":true},
{"id":"eacb400d-827d-4ab4-b515-423dbb90d927","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"TRANSFER_DOMESTIC","quota":5,"tncDescription":"Free 5x transfer to any bank voucher","points":2000,"validity":"2021-10-08","status":true},
{"id":"7b4cde23-ffb1-4f94-8d74-d1be4b379342","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"TOP_UP","quota":10,"tncDescription":"Free 10x top up e-wallet (OVO, GOPAY, Shopee Pay)","points":750,"validity":"2021-10-08","status":true},{"id":"92753ea2-0dc4-4605-a130-0c43f8f3b00f","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"PAYMENT_BILL_PLN","quota":3,"tncDescription":"Free 3x PLN bill payment fee","points":1000,"validity":"2022-01-08","status":true},
{"id":"9dc7de52-1174-43a9-abc1-c9889e2982ba","category":"VOUCHER","usage":"PAYMENT_BILL_PDAM","quota":3,"tncDescription":"Free 3x PDAM bill payment fee","points":1000,"validity":"2022-01-08","status":true},
{"id":"dbe15d75-5550-49cb-8b5f-42aa85c2246f","category":"VOUCHER","usage":"PAYMENT_BILL_INTERNET","quota":3,"tncDescription":"Free 3x Indihome or FirstMedia or Biznet bill payment fee","points":1000,"validity":"2022-01-08","status":true}]

const [offer,voucher] = [data.filter(x => x.category === "JALIN_OFFER"),data.filter(x => x.category === "VOUCHER")]

console.log(voucher,'----',offer)
```

Answer (score 2):

assign [] to voucher

```
let voucher = [], offer = [];  

data.forEach(element => {
            (element.category === "VOUCHER") ? 
            voucher.push(element)  : offer.push(element)
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

With  let voucher, offer = []  offer is empty array [] and voucher is undefined

```js
data = [{"id":"3d59db2c-b561-4978-89bf-9aea17f14e2d","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"TRANSFER_DOMESTIC","quota":10,"tncDescription":"Free 10x transfer to any bank","points":7000,"validity":"2022-01-08","status":true},
{"id":"57db1973-7e42-4992-a4f5-ce578fb78b8a","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"TRANSFER_DOMESTIC","quota":3,"tncDescription":"Free 3x transfer to any bank voucher","points":1500,"validity":"2021-10-08","status":true},
{"id":"eacb400d-827d-4ab4-b515-423dbb90d927","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"TRANSFER_DOMESTIC","quota":5,"tncDescription":"Free 5x transfer to any bank voucher","points":2000,"validity":"2021-10-08","status":true},
{"id":"7b4cde23-ffb1-4f94-8d74-d1be4b379342","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"TOP_UP","quota":10,"tncDescription":"Free 10x top up e-wallet (OVO, GOPAY, Shopee Pay)","points":750,"validity":"2021-10-08","status":true},{"id":"92753ea2-0dc4-4605-a130-0c43f8f3b00f","category":"JALIN_OFFER","usage":"PAYMENT_BILL_PLN","quota":3,"tncDescription":"Free 3x PLN bill payment fee","points":1000,"validity":"2022-01-08","status":true},
{"id":"9dc7de52-1174-43a9-abc1-c9889e2982ba","category":"VOUCHER","usage":"PAYMENT_BILL_PDAM","quota":3,"tncDescription":"Free 3x PDAM bill payment fee","points":1000,"validity":"2022-01-08","status":true},
{"id":"dbe15d75-5550-49cb-8b5f-42aa85c2246f","category":"VOUCHER","usage":"PAYMENT_BILL_INTERNET","quota":3,"tncDescription":"Free 3x Indihome or FirstMedia or Biznet bill payment fee","points":1000,"validity":"2022-01-08","status":true}]

let voucher = []
let offer = []    
data.forEach(element => {
            return (element.category === "VOUCHER") ? 
            voucher.push(element) : offer.push(element)
 });
 console.log(voucher )
 console.log(offer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change   let voucher, offer = []   to  **let voucher = []; let offer = [];**

```
data.forEach(element =>  (element.category === "VOUCHER") ?   voucher.push(element)  : offer.push(element));
```